# Warning Message if Textbox is Clicked

Tags: jquery, html-table, warnings

I have a HTML table, which is dynamically populated using a script.

I would like to use a jQuery script, that will display an error message if the value in column 2 is equal to "Specific Term" when the user clicks into a textbox on the same row.

I've had a search online, but I cannot find any code to achieve this - is there any code like this around?

Comment: what have you done... post your realted codes too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle for you, see if it suits your needs and let me know should you have any questions.

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/rqwaR/)

```
<table class="yourtable">
    <tr>
        <td>abcd</td>
        <td>Specific Term</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="yourtextbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('table.yourtable').on('click','input.yourtextbox',function(){
        var yourval = $(this).parents('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text().trim();
        if (yourval == 'Specific Term') {
            alert('go for it');
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - my table has 8 columns.  The text is is column 2, and the textbox in column 8 - will that change the code?

Comment: @DustinCook This code works for any number of colums. Try for yourself.

Comment: Got it working thanks!  I have a formatting issue where I include a space around the text in each column - but the `trim()` function ignores that!

Comment: @DustinCook Can't really help further without seeing your actual code, can I :). Anyway, glad it worked for you! And good luck with the rest ;)

Answer (score 0):

HTML sample:

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td class="column1"></td>

         <td class="column2"></td>

         <td class="clicked_column"><input type="text" class="textBox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.clicked_column .textBox').click(function(){
           var firstColumn=$(this).closest('tr').find('.column1').text();
           var secondColumn=$(this).closest('tr').find('.column2').text();
           if(secondColumn=='specific value'){
                 alert('alert generated');
           }
     });
});
```